# Linux - Make powertop tweaks only temporary

Tags: linux, battery, powertop

I use ubuntu linux. I usually have 6hrs of battery life. However I'd like to squeeze in more.
I'm afraid to use `powertop` because I don't know if the tweaks are permanent or last until reboot.

How to make them only temporary?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make powertop settings permanent, but `auto-tune` might be
good enough.

To have it run at boot add to `/etc/rc.local` (or as in your distribution),
an executable script that will be launched on boot, such as:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sudo powertop --auto-tune
exit 0
```

To verify that it launched, reboot and open `powertop`, go to the "Tunables" tab,
and check that all the options are set as "Good".

Some points:

1. Keep powertop running while the laptop is on battery, as it needs to collect
   information about your battery and laptop.
2. When running auto-tune, powertop may give some errors although
   it worked as intended.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049068/cant-auto-tune-powertop)